# msg: the etag value in the request header does not match with the current etag value

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a WPF program that interacts with SQL Server 2008 R2 on a remote server via an ODATA interface.

The program just started catching the error "the etag value in the request header does not match with the current etag value". I suspect this has something to do with possible changes to the table on the server.

The closest I cam to anything on the web is this [post](http://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/etag-value-in-header-different-from-object-etag/) dealing with insert triggers. This table does not have any triggers.

Has anyone else run across this and do you have any ideas on how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was and how to work around it for my specific case. The table in question had an index with two columns forming a concatenated key. When the index is set as non-unique there was no problem.

When the index was changed to unique with ignore dupes then this error started occurring. By changing the index back to non-unique the problem went away.

I hope this helps someone. I still don't understand why this occurs, how to debug it, or how to fix it.